# Calculation / formula on data within Workshop

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have an object set that determines an output based on 3 columns values. Let's say column 1 is a money value and column 2 is a year value. These two values divided determine the output and specific number value.

How would I have a user input different numbers and also have the output change? Is there a way to input a specific formula within Workshop?

I have researched this and determined there are functions and scenarios? What would be the fastest and best way to do have an interactive dashboard for users to change the output?

I attempted scenarios and functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay within workshop, you can do this without using either Functions or Scenarios.

1. Create two numeric inputs, one for "money" and "year".
2. Go to "Variables" > "+" > "Numeric" > "Variable Transformation"
3. Search and select "Divide"
4. Choose the "money" and "year" variables from the inputs you defined before.

This will create a new numeric variable that will update automatically as the inputs change.

Comment: Thank you! This helped solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Workshop to create a dashboard, try using Quiver Dashboards instead. They're purpose-built for building interactive dashboards with objects and object sets.